# How to select an object using a string? vb

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I want to set a new image for the picturebox which I click on.
so I thought that I could sent it all on the same clickevent(SelectEvent6x6) and then use sender.name to identify wish picturebox needs to change.
This however doesn't work since it is a string not a object

```
    Private Sub SelectEvent6x6(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles PB00.Click, PB55.Click, PB54.Click, PB53.Click, PB52.Click, PB51.Click, PB50.Click, PB45.Click, PB44.Click, PB43.Click, PB42.Click, PB41.Click, PB40.Click, PB35.Click, PB34.Click, PB33.Click, PB32.Click, PB31.Click, PB30.Click, PB25.Click, PB24.Click, PB23.Click, PB22.Click, PB21.Click, PB20.Click, PB15.Click, PB14.Click, PB13.Click, PB12.Click, PB11.Click, PB10.Click, PB05.Click, PB04.Click, PB03.Click, PB02.Click, PB01.Click
        Dim Selected As String
        Selected = sender.name
        'PB00.Image = Image.FromFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\objects20130308b\map\mapgrassselected.png")
        Selected.Image = Image.FromFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\objects20130308b\map\mapgrassselected.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender should be the picturebox itself, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Dim picBox as PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath)
```